# Access old files after btrfs conversion

Tags: mount, btrfs, conversion, disk-image

I have a disc with a few hundred gigs of relatively unimportant data which I've converted from ext4 to btrfs. The conversion has produced a new empty btrfs partition with a snapshot called "ext2_saved" (yes ext2 not ext4...?).  Within the folder ext2_saved I find a file named image.

I now want to copy the files from the old ext4 filesystem into the new btrfs filesystem, but despite extensive googling I can't find a way to do this.  I would assume I have to mount the image file somehow but mount loop doesn't work.  I haven't got a blank HDD to dd it to but I can order one if this is an option.

**Edit**:  I've now rolled back the conversion which was successful.  I now have the following partition:

```
Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 4294967294 4294965247   2T 83 Linux
```

But when I try to mount this I get "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error."

Any ideas...?

Comment: It's weird that the filesystem is empty. See if this helps: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Conversion_from_Ext3/4_and_ReiserFS

Comment: I've replied by editing above, won't let me post what I need in this comment box!

Comment: What command are you using to mount the filesystem?

Comment: I don't recall now but similar to mount -o loop /path/to/image /mnt/disk

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion;

Still not sure what had gone wrong, but it turned out that converting MBR to GPT on the disk and then running a fsck -y on the volume fixed it.  I was then able to mount the partition and copy off the data.

Lesson; playing with converting filesystems is fun but occasionally frustrating.